# How do i get a class instance in Extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I defined a class 'IMS.SellMgt.testForm'.when i click the button 'submit',i want to get 'var test = this.formPanel;',why test is null? if i want to get this.formPanel,how can i do?Thank you!

```
    Ext.define('IMS.SellMgt.testForm', {
    formPanel: null,
    LoadForm: function () {
            this.formPanel = new Ext.form.Panel({
            renderTo: 'form-ct',
            frame: true,
            title: 'XML Form',
            width: 300,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                title: 'Contact Information',
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                    emptyText: 'First Name',
                    name: 'first'
                }
            ]
            }],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Submit',
                handler: function () {
                    var test = this.formPanel;
                        }
            }]
        });
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var frmTest = Ext.create('IMS.SellMgt.testForm', {});
    frmTest.LoadForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
......
handler: function () {
    var test = this.findParentByType(Ext.form.FormPanel);
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

`handler` is a simpler way of specifying a click event listener for the button. Since it is short hand, it has some drawbacks.

With `handler`, the context of the function is always the button. In other words, `this` inside the handler function is the button, not your form.

In order for `this` to be your class, use a listener with a scope specified:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Submit',
    listeners: {
        click: function() {
            this.formPanel; // will work now
            ...
        },
        scope: this // this is the key
    }
}]
```

You can also use `up` to find the form:

```
handler: function() {
    var form = this.up('form');
    ...
}
```